# Show simple modal dialog using JQuery

Tags: jquery

There is the simple following div:

```
<div id="dialogg">
    Hello, world!
</div>
```

Some CSS style:

```
#dialogg {
    display: none;
}
```

And JQuery code:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#dialogg').dialog({
            autoOpen: false;
            width: 400;
        });
        $('#dialogg').dialog('open');
    });
</script>
```

But I see no dialogs! How can I fix it? What's wrong?

UPDATE:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Исторический турнир</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main-styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/departments-page-styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#dialogg').show();
            $('#dialogg').dialog({
                autoOpen: false;
                width: 400;
            });
            $('#dialogg').dialog('open');
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

But this code doesn't still work.

Answer (score 2):

please try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and just try:  **`$("#dialogg").dialog();`**

```
<script>
 $(function() {
   $( "#dialogg").dialog();
 });
</script>
```

see [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j2SBE/)

[example on jquery site](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need two ui.js script there remove one.. and looks like you forgot to load the css file

add this on top of the script..

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

so the full code should be

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#dialogg').dialog({
        autoOpen: false;
        width: 400;
    });
    $('#dialogg').dialog('open');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not waiting for the html document to be fully loaded completely as far as the browser is concerned when you are selecting `$('#dialog')` it does not exist. You can either use the `<script>...</script>` lower in the html or add the function in `$('document').ready(function(){..});`

Answer (score 0):

Also this is incorrect:

```
$('#dialogg').dialog({
  autoOpen: false;
  width: 400;
});
```

it should be:

```
$('#dialogg').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  width: 400
});
```